# jQuery duration for toggleClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change style class of div element during 1 second with some effect. This is my code. When I execute this example style switches immediately without effects and timeouts. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$("#changeStyle").click(function() {
$("#divka").toggleClass("a1","slow");
return false;
});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>


</head>
<body>
<div id="divka"></div>
<input type="button" id="changeStyle" value="change style"/>
</body>



.a1 {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:#eee;
width:200px;
height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

toggleClass do not animate the style attributes you have to use animate method of JQuery.

```
$("#divka").animate({
borderWidth: "1px",
borderColor: "#000",
borderStyle: "solid",
backgroundColor:"#eee",
width:"200px",
height:"400px",
}, 500);
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But if the css is not such trivial what then? Is this only way?

Comment: Yes this is the only way to animate multiple styles of any dom element.

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass has nothing to do with "slow"-like params - this is valid for for methods, using animations.

Check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

The [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function doesn't work that way. The behaviour you're looking for is accomplished with the jQuery UI [switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/) function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [addClass()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/) or [switchClass()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/) which is part odf jquery UI:

```
$("#divka").addClass("a1",500);
```